# iPad: Disable low battery automatic power-off

Tags: ios, ipad

My iPad (running iOS 11.4.1) is charged at 100% but suffers from continuous rebooting due to intermittent detection of battery charger level of less than 1%.

I have to hard power-off, reboot and the iPad will show `100%` battery level - until it decides the level were actually `<1%` - at which point it auto shuts down.

I just want to disable the automatic shutdown since the problem is simply intermittent faulty battery level detection not actual ground truth level.

Is there a setting for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**.

There is no user level setting available to disable power off due to low battery. iOS is programmed to turn the device off in case a low charge is detected (and under various other scenarios).

In your case, it appears that the battery is misbehaving. It is recommended to get your iPad inspected by an authorized technician.

Comment: ok well an unhappy answer - yet a correct one - still merits the award.

Comment: know anyone who wants to fix this for <=$100 ? ;)

Comment: What's the model of your iPad and when did you bought it? If it's still under warranty (<1 year of purchase or covered under Apple Care), you may be eligible for free service/replacement. Check with your nearest Apple Store.

Comment: `ML0G2LLA` ; it's definitely not in the 1 year warranty

Comment: Having looked at the specs  https://www.amazon.com/Apple-iPad-32GB-Wi-Fi-Silver/dp/B0155KDJWA  Is it possible to downgrade `ios` ?  I'm wondering if the problem were a version 11.x issue..  I have no idea if it were possible to revert to say ios 10.X

Comment: That's not the model identifier. It should be of the form `A1XXX` where XXX are digits. It is mentioned on the back side of the device towards bottom centre.

Comment: No. It won't be possible to downgrade to any release below iOS 11.4.1. And no it is very likely "not" an iOS issue.

Comment: I did find the device by using that identifier.  In any case what you're looking for is `A1584`